# What is the timeout for items getting removed from cache when using org.springframework.cache.annotation.Cacheable

Tags: java, spring-boot

Im using a @Cacheable annotation for caching data from my GET Request. Im just wondering what is the default timeout for items getting removed from the cache. I cant really find anything to say what it is.

Answer (score 2):

The timeout for items getting removed from cache when using org.springframework.cache.annotation.Cacheable is defined by the `Cache Manager`.

You can refer to this [article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cache-tutorial)